# How to get checkbox state in expandable listview in android

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I want to know checkbox state in expandable listview in my application data come from server.

My **ProductsCategory.java**:-

```
    public class ProductsCategory extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private GridView gridView;
    ProductsAdapter  adapter;
    ProductsAdapterGridView adapterGridView;
    ArrayList<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String menu_id;
    TextView textView,textViewfilter;

    // Filter Class
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.produts_category);

        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Shopping Mazza");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        menu_id = i.getStringExtra("category");
        adapter = new ProductsAdapter(ProductsCategory.this,R.layout.product_page_list_view,productsList);
        adapterGridView = new ProductsAdapterGridView(ProductsCategory.this,R.layout.products_page_grid_view,productsList);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.filter_expandable_list_view);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_product);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.list_product_grid);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.change_view);
        textViewfilter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        textViewfilter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (expListView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                    listDataHeader.clear();
                    listDataChild.clear();

                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(ProductsCategory.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    expListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                        expListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // preparing list data
                    //    prepareListData();
                    new PrepareListData().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/filters&key=test123$");

                    // Listview Group click listener
                    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return false;

                        }
                    });

                    // Listview Group expanded listener
                    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    // Listview Group collasped listener
                    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                    // Listview on child click listener
                    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                            + " : "
                                            + listDataChild.get(
                                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                 /*   Intent i = new Intent(ProductsCategory.this,FilterClass.class);
                    i.putExtra("category_id",menu_id);
                    startActivity(i);*/
                }
            }
        });

        new Product().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/products&key=test123$");
    }
    public class PrepareListData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected synchronized void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(ProductsCategory.this);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected synchronized  Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category",menu_id));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("filters");

                    //     Log.d("jsonarray",jsonArray.length()+"");

                    Log.d("filter",jsonArray+"");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String s = jsonObject1.getString("filter_group_id");
                        listDataHeader.add(jsonObject1.getString("name"));

                        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("filter");

                        List<String> firstlevel = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(int j=0;j<jsonArray1.length();j++){

                            JSONObject jsonObject11 = jsonArray1.optJSONObject(j);

                            String s1 = jsonObject11.getString("filter_id");
                            String colorcode = jsonObject11.getString("colorcode");
                            firstlevel.add(jsonObject11.getString("name"));
                        }
                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), firstlevel);
                        Log.d("listDataHeader", listDataHeader.get(i)+"");
                        Log.d("value of", firstlevel + "");
                        Log.d("hash map", listDataChild.size() + "");
                        //  firstlevel.clear();
                    }
                }
            }catch (IOException |JSONException e){
                Log.e("Error :", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected synchronized void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //  super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            dialog.dismiss();
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(ProductsCategory.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        }
    }
```

My **ExpandableListAdapter**:-

```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_filter, null);


        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group_filter, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to know which button is checkbox is checked and call a userdefine methods.One more thing when i check a checkbox and collasped group and then again expanded the group the position of checkbox is change.

I give snapshot of both position:-

[image]

when i collasped and again expanded check box position is change.

[image]

Comment: is the provided answer working for you? If not what's missing/unclear?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is actually similiar to a listview with checkboxes. You need to remember the state internally (e.g. with a boolean array or set) and provide a getter on the state.

1. Get the checkbox from your child layout and add a listener

   ```
   public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
       ...
       private final Set<Pair<Long, Long>> mCheckedItems = new HashSet<Pair<Long, Long>>();
       ...
       public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

           ...

           final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id);
           // add tag to remember groupId/childId
           final Pair<Long, Long> tag = new Pair<Long, Long>(
               getGroupId(groupPosition),
               getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));
           cb.setTag(tag);
           // set checked if groupId/childId in checked items
           cb.setChecked(mCheckedItems.contains(tag));
           // set OnClickListener to handle checked switches
           cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                   final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                   final Pair<Long, Long> tag = (Pair<Long, Long>) v.getTag();
                   if (cb.isChecked()) {
                       mCheckedItems.add(tag);
                   } else {
                       mCheckedItems.remove(tag);
                   }
               }
           });

           ...

       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Add a getter for your checked state

   ```
   public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
       ...
       public Set<Pair<Long, Long>> getCheckedItems() {
           return mCheckedItems;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

The sparsely filled Set contains all checked group/child items. You can call the method e.g. in your activity.

Regarding your second question: i assume when collapsing/expanding a group the checked child is incorrect because of some internally reused child views now at a different position.

Also don't forget to the following layout attributes on the checkbox item to not loose click events for the child item.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: I have tried many answers on stackoverflow. None of them worked for me except this. Thanks alot